# Formal definition of "$\Rightarrow$" relation (derivation relation) for context-free grammars

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, context-free-grammar

This is probably more of a logic question.
I'm looking for formal definition of derivation relation for context-free grammars (CFGs). The books on subject tend to define derivation relation for CFGs in two ways (here I'm using "$\rightarrow$" for material implication, "$\mapsto$" for production relation and "$\Rightarrow$" for derivation relation):

1. Let G(V, T, P, S) be a CFG, then:
   $$\forall \alpha (\forall \beta (\forall \gamma (\forall A (\alpha \in (V \cup T)^* \land \beta \in (V \cup T)^* \land \gamma \in (V \cup T)^* \land A \in V \rightarrow \quad ([A \mapsto \gamma] \in P \rightarrow [\alpha A \beta \Rightarrow \alpha \gamma \beta]) \quad )))) $$
2. Let G(V, T, P, S) be a CFG, then:
   $$\forall \eta (\forall \phi(\eta \in (V \cup T)^* \land \phi \in (V \cup T)^* \land [\eta \Rightarrow \phi] \rightarrow \quad      (\exists \alpha (\exists \beta (\exists \gamma (\exists A (\alpha \in (V \cup T)^* \land \beta \in (V \cup T)^* \land \gamma \in (V \cup T)^* \land A \in V \quad \land [A \mapsto \gamma] \in P \land \eta=\alpha A \beta \land\phi=\alpha \gamma \beta)))))     \quad ))$$

The second definition is from Wikipedia (written in more cumbersome notation).Then there is a definition of reflexive transitive closure of =>:

Let G(V, T, P, S) be a CFG, then

- $\forall \alpha(\alpha \in (V \cup T)^* \rightarrow [\alpha \Rightarrow ^* \alpha] )$
- $\forall \alpha(\forall \beta( \forall \gamma ( \alpha \in (V \cup T)^* \land \beta \in (V \cup T)^* \land \gamma \in (V \cup T)^* \rightarrow \quad ([\alpha \Rightarrow ^* \beta] \land [\beta \Rightarrow \gamma] \rightarrow [\alpha \Rightarrow ^* \gamma]) \quad )))$

Now, in proofs regarding CFGs (for example, proof that if there is a derivation tree in G for $w$, then $S \Rightarrow ^* w$) we use the following theorem:

Let G(V, T, P, S) be a CFG, then
$$\forall \eta (\forall \phi ( \eta \in (V \cup T)^* \land \phi \in (V \cup T)^* \land [\eta \Rightarrow \phi] \rightarrow \quad (\forall \alpha (\forall \beta (\alpha \in (V \cup T)^* \land \beta \in (V \cup T)^* \rightarrow [\alpha \eta \beta \Rightarrow \alpha \phi \beta])) ) \quad ))$$

This theorem, as I understand it, describes the essence of "context-freeness": if we can derive one string from another, then we can perform such derivation in any surrounding context.

Now, to prove this last theorem, *both* definitions of => relation are used. I've tried to derive one definition from another, but failed.

**The question is: are these two definitions equivalent, or the correct definition is actually a conjunction of these two?**

Remark:
I've tried using mace4 to find counterexample and succeeded. Here are the definitions I used:

```
formulas(assumptions).
    % string axioms
    exists x (symbol(x)).

    string(e).
    all x (symbol(x) -> string(x)).
    all x (all y (string(x) & string(y) -> string(x + y))).

    all x (string(x) -> x = x).
    all x (string(x) -> x = x + e).
    all x (string(x) -> x = e + x).
    all x (
        all y (
            string(x) & string(y) -> (
                x = y -> (
                    exists s (
                        exists w (
                            symbol(s) & string(w) & x = s + w & y = s + w
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ).
end_of_list.

formulas(assumptions).
    exists s ( exists w (symbol(s) & string(w) & production(s, w))).

    all x (
        all y (
            string(x) & string(y) & derivation(x, y) -> (
                exists s (
                    exists w (
                        exists a (
                            exists b (
                                symbol(s) & string(w) & string(a) & string(b) & production(s, w) & x = (a + s) + b & y = (a + w) + b
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ).
end_of_list.

formulas(goals).
    all s (
        all w (
            all a (
                all b (
                    symbol(s) & string(w) & string(a) & string(b) & production(s, w) -> (
                        derivation((a + s) + b, (a + w) + b)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ).
end_of_list.
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It is generally the case in rewrite systems that $\eta\rightsquigarrow\phi$ implies $\alpha\eta\beta\rightsquigarrow\alpha\phi\beta$; that is not specific to _context-free_ grammars. What _is_ specific to "context free" is that the string on the left-hand-side of a _primitive_ rewriting is a single symbol -- which means that the possible fates of a symbol you find in one of the intermediate strings depends only on the symbol itself, and not of which context you find that symbol in.

Comment: For example, a grammar that is not context-free might contain rules such as $ABC ::= ADEC$ where a $B$ can turn to $DE$ but only if there's an $A$ to the left and a $C$ to the right. (Allowing such rules makes general grammars Turing-complete, so it is not decidable wheter a given grammar can generate a given string).

Comment: I understand. What I'm trying to ask here is whether one definition follows from the other. The first definition basically says that if there is a *production* [A -> w], then for all a, b: [aAn => awb]. This definition is presented in "Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation". But can one logically infer from such definition the following (which is the second definition): if for two strings w0, w1 relation holds ([w0 => w1]), then there have to be strings a, b and a production [A -> w], such that w0 = aAb and w1 = awb?

Comment: OK, after contemplating a bit more, I decided that indeed both definitions should be in conjunction. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is like the relation between an [inference rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_inference) and the *derivation* concept in math logic.

An inference rule, like e.g. [modus ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens) is a single elementary inferential step.

The [derivability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnstile_(symbol)#Interpretations) relation holds between a formula $\varphi$ and a set of formulas $\Gamma$ (in symbols : $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$) iiff we have a "chain" of elementary inferential steps (i.e. applications of the rules of inference) starting from the formulas in $\Gamma$ (the *assumptions* or *axioms*) and ending with $\varphi$.

---

In the field of [Context-free grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) we have *production rules* :

> a single elementary "transformational" step that licenses the transformation (replacement) of string $\alpha$ with string $\beta$.

In this case, we say that $\alpha$ directly yields $\beta$; in symbols :

> $\alpha \Rightarrow \beta$ (or, according to you : $\alpha ↦ \beta$).

And we have the repetitive application of production rules : $\alpha \Rightarrow^* \beta$, meaning that there is a chain of applications of production rules starting with $\alpha$ and ending with $\beta$.

---

Having said that, a formal definition must be inductive :

$\alpha \Rightarrow^* \beta$ iff :

> either  *(i)* there is a *production rule* $R$ such that $(\alpha, \beta) \in R$, i.e. $\alpha \Rightarrow \beta$,
>
> or *(ii)* there is a string $\gamma$ and a production rule $R$ such that :
>
> > $\alpha \Rightarrow^* \gamma$ and $\gamma \Rightarrow \beta$.

Comment: I guess I've presented my question in the wrong form. What I'm trying to ask here is whether one definition follows from the other. The first definition basically says that if there is a production [A -> w], then for all a, b: [aAn => awb]. This definition is presented in "Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation". But can one logically infer from such definition the following (which is the second definition): if for two strings w0, w1 relation holds ([w0 => w1]), then there have to be strings a, b and a production [A -> w], such that w0 = aAb and w1 = awb?

Comment: If it is like modus ponens, then these two definitions have to be in conjuction: in one direction, if there is a production, then we can add any context and get derivation; in the other direction, if there is derivation, then there has to be a production. So both books and Wikipedia give incomplete definitions for derivation relation. Thank you.